# Moving from OWL/XML to RDF/XML

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, owl-api

I was developing an ontology in Protege and my file had the OWL/XML format. [Due to a problem with labels when using the OWLAPI](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues/748) I saved this file as RDF/XML (just using the `Save as` option on Protege 5.2.0).

I have just noticed that as a result of this both my `DataProperties` and `ObjectProperties` have become now `AnnotationProperties`. I haven't actually lost my properties, but new `AnnotationProperties` with the same names where created, which leads to errors like this when loading the ontology:

```
Level:       ERROR
Time:        1524007564597
Message:     Illegal redeclarations of entities: reuse of entity http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula-professors#hasNationality in punning not allowed [ObjectProperty: hasNationality, AnnotationProperty: hasNationality]
```

But my main issue is that the individuals that where related using this properties are now related only through `AnnotationProperties` which makes no sense.

**Before:**

[image]

```
<ObjectPropertyAssertion>
  <ObjectProperty IRI="http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula#partOf"/>
  <NamedIndividual IRI="#Mathematics"/>
  <NamedIndividual IRI="#Basic_Sciences"/>
</ObjectPropertyAssertion>
```

**After:**

[image]

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula-instance#Mathematics">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula#Thematic_Area"/>
  <curricula:partOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula-instance#Basic_Sciences"/>
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="es">Matemáticas</rdfs:label>
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Mathematics</rdfs:label>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

See that the code there shows the same relation `Mathematics partOf Basic_Sciences` before and after the change.

Is this normal? Is there a way to prevent it? Or is there a way of using OWLAPI that work with OWL/XML and doesn't generate the label problem?

Thanks

Comment: This is not normal and this should not happen. Missing declaration axioms for the properties are the reason that the OWL API parser doesn't know the type of the property. AFAIK, Protege 5.2.0 still uses OWL API v4, thus, the issue is not directly related to yours especially as you said this just happens when you save the ontology as RDF/XML and load back? Or did I misunderstand this?

Comment: I believe Protege has an option to choose to add missing declarations to its output - that's what is required for declarations that are not in the ontology to be added. You could also manually modify the RDF/XML file to add them, if this is a one off conversion step.

Comment: @Ignazio I redo the transformation on a different computer an this didn't happen.

Comment: @AKSW But I'm pretty sure that's how this happened in the first place since I have two commits with 15 minutes of difference that give me the before and after. I will see if I can replicate this on the computer that I used in the first case an open an issue. Thanks!